# SQLite separating two random numbers

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

```
public void Isrinkzaidejapirma(){
    String sql = "SELECT rowid FROM Veiksmai WHERE Pirmas < 4 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 2";

    try (Connection conn = this.connect();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){
        while (rs.next()) {
            int zaidejas1id = rs.getInt("rowid");
            //System.out.println(rs.getInt(zaidejas2id));
            System.out.println(zaidejas1id);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

With this code I'm getting 2 random numbers. (For example 4 2, 1 2 and etc.).
How can I separate them into two variables?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `while (rs.next())` loop, how about just using

```java
Integer value1 = null, value2 = null;
if (rs.next()) {
    value1 = rs.getInt("rowid");
    if (rs.next()) {
        value2 = rs.getInt("rowid");
    }
}
```

Then you could use one of those values in a subsequent query like so:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Pirmas FROM Veiksmai WHERE rowid=?");
ps.setInt(1, value1);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Wow, it works. But can you tell how it works? I'm trying to understand. If with String sql = "SELECT rowid FROM Veiksmai WHERE Pirmas < 4 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 2"; im getting two numbers, how value1 and value2 splits those numbers in to variables? Thank you!

Comment: Your query will return a maximum of two rows (`LIMIT 2`). The ResultSet is initially positioned before the first row. Each time you call `rs.next()` it moves to the next row and returns `true`, or if there are no more rows it returns `false`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, but now i have last question. After you showed me how to get those variables i want to do next: take value1 or value2 and use it in another sql string: ""SELECT Pirmas FROM Veiksmai WHERE rowid=value1". Sqlite doesnt let use int value1 as number or what? I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: @AndreKostalante Please read up on how to [use prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) in Java. You can't just use a variable name in a query string and expect that to work. You need to use a parameter placeholder (`?`) and use `setInt(1, value1)`.

Comment: Guys, thank you very much. I'm learning JAVA by myself and sometimes it could look like i'm asking really stupid questions, sorry for that. You really helped me and i learned today a lot. Thank you again!